# How to include large amount of assets (images) in UWP app

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I'm looking for a way to include 75,000 (~750MB) png files in UWP app.

Adding them as content within the project throws an error on build:

```
Processing Resources failed with error : Too many resources defined for package.
```

and makes Visual Studio unbearably slow. The .csproj file is 4MB in size.

I've also tried adding them to a separate project, as Build Action: None and Copy to Output : Always. It builds, and it somewhat does what it should, but it's not really usable. Wrong click in VS and it gets stuck for 15-20 minutes

Edit:

Manually packaging the app might be an option but I haven't had the chance to try yet. Another idea I've had is to zip all assets during build process, and unzip them on first install into a local folder.

Comment: Why don't you put them in local folder? Why  don't  you put them in a server ? What are these images for? As the error detail mentioned, "Too many resources defined for package", you should avoid to put so large amounts of files in the install folder.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT The images are icons and renders of various items. I want the app to work offline so I'm looking for a way to bundle the artwork with the app.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not a good practice. You could consider one time download all the images in the local folder once user install the app. Then your app could using these images in local folder offline.

Comment: I wonder if your png files can be split into several  localized subsets (en-us, de-de) ? If this is the case you can use "resource packages" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2016/09/30/optimizing-the-download-of-universal-windows-apps-with-resource-packages/ .